# Código só me retorna a primeira linha da tabela referente ao ID do paciênte

Tags: php, pdo

O código só me retorna a primeira linha da tabela referente ao ID do paciênte

```
<?php
require 'conexao.php';

// Recebe o id do exame do exame via GET
$id_exames = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : '';


// Valida se existe um id e se ele é numérico
  if (!empty($id_exames) && is_numeric($id_exames)):

    // Captura os dados do exame solicitado
    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT  id,codigo,data,exame,data2  FROM historico where id='.$id_exames;   
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':id', $id_exames);
    $stm->execute();
    $exames = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);



  endif;

?>
```

Comment: Não compreendi. Coloque o sql do código e se possível fale como esta sua tabela no banco. Para ficar mais fácil de te ajudar...

Comment: A função do `PDO` `fetch` só lista um elemento, para listar todos que retornam na consulta, deves usar: `fetchAll`

Answer (score 4):

Você tem duas opções para pegar mais de um dado nesse contexto.

Uma delas é fazer isso:

```
while( $exames = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ) {
    // este loop vai ser executado uma vez para cada linha.
    print_r( $exames ); // para você ver como o resultado vem neste caso
}
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

A outra é recuperar tudo em uma estrutura só:

```
$exames = $stm->fetchAll()
print_r( $exames ); // para você ver como o resultado vem neste caso
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Olá, muito obrigada

Comment: Todos os registros referente ao pacientes foram mostrados, mas nao apareceram dentro da tabela como antes   <td><?=$exames->codigo?></td>
    <td><?=$exames->data?></td>
 <td><?=$exames->exame?>
 <td><?=$exames->data2?></td>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require 'conexao.php';

// Recebe o id do exame do exame via GET
$id_exames = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : '';


// Valida se existe um id e se ele é numérico
  if (!empty($id_exames) && is_numeric($id_exames)):

    // Captura os dados do exame solicitado
    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = "SELECT  id,codigo,data,exame,data2  FROM historico where id=:id";   
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':id', $id_exames, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();
    $exames = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);



  endif;

?>
```